# Ubuntu ramdisk template

Tags: dhcp, boot, pxe-boot, initramfs

I've been working on a ramdisk template for running a complete root filesystem on the RAM of a baremetal server(over IPMI so no physical access) that boots over PXE.
I used `debootstrap` to create an ubuntu trusty filesystem and applied some modifications.
The server boots successfully and mounts the root filesystem on /dev/ram0, however, network never comes up and the login prompt doesn't respond for keyboard input.

Here are the steps that I followed:

1) Create a rootfs file

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=rootfs bs=1k count=$((768 * 1024))
```

2) Create an ext3 file system

```
mkfs.ext3 -m0 -F -L root rootfs
```

3) Create a mount point

```
 mkdir /root/rootfs/
```

4) Mount

```
mount -t ext3 -o loop rootfs /root/rootfs
```

5) Debootstrapping Ubuntu trusty

```
debootstrap --arch=amd64  trusty /root/rootfs
```

6) chroot /root/rootfs

```
chroot /root/rootfs
```

7) vi /etc/fstab

```
/dev/ram0   /           ext2        defaults        0       0
proc        /proc       proc        defaults        0       0 
none        /tmp        tmpfs       defaults        0       0 
none        /var/run    tmpfs       defaults        0       0 
none        /var/lock   tmpfs       defaults        0       0 
none        /var/tmp    tmpfs       defaults        0       0
```

8) /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

9) Some other modifications

```
......
```

10) Umounting and compressing the image

```
gzip -c rootfs | dd of=/path/to/webserver/rootfs.gz
```

11) Copying the kernel to webserver

```
cp /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) /path/to/webserver/
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try adding

5.1)

```
# cp /etc/hostname /root/rootfs/etc/
# cp /etc/hosts /root/rootfs/etc/
```

6)

```
# mount --bind /dev  /root/rootfs/dev
# mount --bind /proc /root/rootfs/proc
# mount --bind /sys  /root/rootfs/sys
# chroot /root/rootfs/ /bin/bash --login
```

[source](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I couldn't get it to work so I just turned to creating a custom CentOS LiveCD using the `livecd-creator` tool.